Rigging the eyes
So I am trying something new. Rigging a set of eyes that I created by modifying the original model. Unfortunately, no matter how I rig it, it stretches in weird ways that I didn't want. Can someone maybe help me with the process?
Maybe its is how I set up the eye rig?
Or do I need to edit the eye mesh itself?
I put the link of the Blender file below to try answering.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DjPpZI0H6ppg0CyrvEjRtsKmplZftHpP/view?usp=sharing


That link is requesting access! If the file is under 30Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

I just made it accessible to anyone with the link

are you taking about the pupils? I can't see them deforming, could you please highlight the problem in a screenshot?

As the eye is not spherical, it will get out of eyesocket when rotating.
The solution is to start with a spherical eye and add a machinary bone (MCH in my example) wich is parent of the deforming eye bone (DEF in my example). Set the head of both bones in the exact center of the sphere, and set the MCH bone child of the character's head bone.
You will use the MCH bone to scale the eye until it matches the desired proportions, then you can rotate the DEF bone to animate the line of sight.


Without downloading the blend file, but having encountered similar issues, I have a suggestion.

make sure your eyes are completely detached from all other parts of the mesh
place the root of a bone in the dead-center of the volume of the eye (assuming it's a sphere)
make sure that bone completely affects the eye via weight painting
make sure no other bones affect the eye via weight painting
make sure the eye bone is properly parented to another bone, like the head bone.

if done correctly, by rotating this bone the eye should rotate. You can then have the bone point towards some other bone to control where the eyes look.
